# swift: random numbers in array

Tags: ios, swift

I have array with numbers

```
var shoppingList: [String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "zero"]
```

I want to show 3 random words from `shoppingList` in my label.

Also I have 10 buttons with numerals `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0`. And I want to enter numerals that equals 3 random words from array in my `textField` and get `print("Done")` if I have success or get `print("not")`. How to do it?

example: for example I get this 3 words `one , five , three` it means that I should press on buttons with numerals `1,5,3` and enter this numerals in the `textField`.

```
@IBAction func numerals(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let number = sender.currentTitle        
    textField.text = textField.text! + number!

    if (textField.text?.count)! > 2 {             
    }        
}
```

**Update**

```
var rand1 = ""
var rand2 = ""
var rand3 = ""

var textField1 = [Int]()
var code = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var shoppingList: [String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "zero"]

        rand1 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
        rand2 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
        rand3 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]

        //ensures rand1 and rand2 are not the same
        while(rand2 == rand1){
            rand2 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
        }
        //ensures rand3 is different from rand1 and rand2
        while(rand3 == rand1 || rand3 == rand2){
            rand3 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
        }

        code = ["\(rand1), \(rand2), \(rand3)"]

        label?.text = "\(rand1), \(rand2), \(rand3)"
}

func wordToNumber(with word: String) -> Int? {
        switch word {
        case "zero":
            return 0
        case "one":
            return 1
        case "two":
            return 2
        case "three":
            return 3
        case "four":
            return 4
        case "five":
            return 5
        case "six":
            return 6
        case "seven":
            return 7
        case "eight":
            return 8
        case "nine":
            return 9
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func checkIfCodeIsCorrect() -> Bool {
        let codeAsNumbers = code.map { return wordToNumber(with: $0) }
        print(codeAsNumbers)
        return codeAsNumbers == textField1
    }

@IBAction func control(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let number = sender.currentTitle

        textField.text = textField.text! + number!

        textField1.append(Int(number!)!)
        print(textField1)

        if (textField.text?.count)! > 2 {

            print(checkIfCodeIsCorrect())

        }

    }
```

Comment: _Please_, write code without `!`s. They hurt my eyes.

Comment: Do you want to display a different value from shoppingList on a button when it's clicked? Or do you want to append a different value from shoppingList each time to a textfield when a button is clicked? Some clarification might help here

Comment: @Raghav for example: I show in label `three , five ,nine`. it means that I should enter in textField `359` and get `done` if I have success.  Or get `not` if I enter, for example `354`

Comment: @user303794 Exactly *what* do you want displayed in the label? `three, five, nine`, `three five nine`, how do you want it? Please update your question.

Comment: @George_E_2 I want to show 3 random words from my `shoppingList` in label. And after that I want to enter 3 numerals (I have 10 buttons `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0`) that equals this words.

Comment: @George_E_2 Did you understand? Or should I add more information?

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: "How to do it?" is not a good question. What is the problem, selecting 3 random numbers or displaying the numbers pressed or evaluating the result or...?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can not understand how to combine words with numbers.

Comment: You mean like `someString.append(String(someNumber))`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson for example, if I see in label `one, five, three` I should press `1,5,3` buttons and get `1,5,3` in textField. How to check that I enter right numbers?

Comment: @user303794 Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you have changed your question, I will submit an answer again.

What you need to do, is simply convert the `String`'s to `Int`'s so you can compare the numbers. Here is the code you need:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


func wordToNumber(with word: String) -> Int? {
    switch word {
    case "zero":
        return 0
    case "one":
        return 1
    case "two":
        return 2
    case "three":
        return 3
    case "four":
        return 4
    case "five":
        return 5
    case "six":
        return 6
    case "seven":
        return 7
    case "eight":
        return 8
    case "nine":
        return 9
    default:
        return nil
    }
}


var textFieldInts = [3, 2, 6, 7, 1]
var code = ["three", "two", "six", "seven", "one"]


func checkIfCodeIsCorrect() -> Bool {
    let codeAsNumbers = code.map { return wordToNumber(with: $0) }

    return codeAsNumbers == textFieldInts
}


print(checkIfCodeIsCorrect()) // Perform task if they are equal by placing an if or guard statement
```

- `textFieldInts` are the values inputed by the user, as `[Int]`.
- `code` is the numbers you are displaying to the user to type in, as `[String]`.

Comment: I update and add new code in question. I get `false` in `checkIfCodeIsCorrect() ` and get `[nil]` in `print(codeAsNumbers)`

Comment: @user303794 I'm not sure I can longer help you... You cannot ask for someone to code for you, but help you. My functions is **plainly** called `wordToNumber`. So don't input a number which is why you get `nil` and `false`.

Comment: No need to write code. I got it. Everything works well. But there is one more question. When I write Foundation in сode, this word crossed out. Why?

Comment: @user303794 You may have already imported `Foundation` in that file. I can't exactly tell without the file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you can do this to get three random values for your textField

```
@IBAction func numerals(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let rand1 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
    var rand2 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
    var rand3 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]

    //ensures rand1 and rand2 are not the same
    while(rand2 == rand1){
        rand2 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
    }
    //ensures rand3 is different from rand1 and rand2
    while(rand3 == rand1 || rand3 == rand2){
        rand3 = shoppingList[Int(arc4random()%(UInt32(shoppingList.count)))]
    }

    let newString = "\(rand1), \(rand2), \(rand3)"

    textField.text = newString
}
```

**NEW QUESTION**

In regards to your new question that you commented, here you go.
I ran this in Playground, and it worked for me. I called it like this:

```
let isCorrect = checkIfCodeIsCorrect()
print("isCorrect \(isCorrect)")
```

This is the other code:

```
var code = ["two","five","seven"]
var textField1 = [2,5,7]

func wordToNumber(with word: String) -> Int{
    switch word {
    case "zero":
        return 0
    case "one":
        return 1
    case "two":
        return 2
    case "three":
        return 3
    case "four":
         return 4
    case "five":
        return 5
    case "six":
        return 6
    case "seven":
        return 7
    case "eight":
        return 8
        case "nine":
        return 9
    default:
        return -1
    }
}

func checkIfCodeIsCorrect() -> Bool {

    var codeAsNumbers = [Int]()
    for i in 0...code.count-1{
        codeAsNumbers.append(wordToNumber(with: code[i]))
    }
    print(codeAsNumbers)
    return codeAsNumbers == textField1
}
```

Obviously, I made test cases because I don’t have the actually code. You will have to adjust a little, but that is the way to do it.

Comment: I want to show this words in label. Not in `textField`. In `textField` I want to get numerals. When I press on buttons I get numerals in `textField`. for example `1,5,6`. How to create check to find out that words from `shoppingList ` equals numerals on buttons?

Comment: I update and add new code in question. I get false in checkIfCodeIsCorrect() and get [nil] in print(codeAsNumbers)

Comment: @user303794 I updated my answer to your new question. If it works for you, don't forget to upvote!

Comment: In this line`codeAsNumbers.append(wordToNumber(with: code[i])!)` I get this: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Try changing the return value for codeAsNumber from Int? to Int. Subsequently, remove the ! from codeAsNumbers.append(wordToNumber(with: code[i]) (fixed it above, also)

Comment: In this case I get `Nil is incompatible with return type 'Int'` in `return nil`

Comment: For your default case, return -1 (you can set it up so if -1 is received, an error happened, if you want)

Comment: I’m also not home right now so I can’t check what I’m saying, but it should work. Any other issues I can adjust when I get in front of my computer. Let me know

Answer (score 1):

One fairly straightforward method is to "shuffle" your array, and then just use the first *n* elements.

So, for your example:

```
// simple shuffle extension
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle() {
        for i in 0 ..< (count - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            swapAt(i, j)
        }
    }
}

// then, inside your function (viewDidLoad, for example)

    var shoppingList: [String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "zero"]

    shoppingList.shuffle()

    print(shoppingList[0], shoppingList[1], shoppingList[2])
```

Each time you run that, you will have different "numbers" at index 0, 1 and 2 (well, because it's a small sample, you *will* occasionally get the same values -- kinda the definition of random).

Comment: Ok. But how to create check to find out that words from shoppingList equals numerals on buttons? For example how I can know that 3 words - `one , five , three` equals 3 button title `1,5,3`. If I enter `1,5,3` in textField I should get `print("Done")`. But if I enter `1,5,4` I should get `print("not")`.